# Sort posts by popularity in Ghost

Tags: database, google-analytics, ghost-blog

I want to sort posts in the sidebar by popularity (views count?), how can I achieve this in Ghost 2.0?

I know that the Ghost(Pro) can insert a tracking pixel on the page, but as I understand it, I can't use this option in the self-hosted Ghost. Can I use Google Analytics for this?

I want to update the sidebar once a certain period of time, say, every 6 hours, or when a new post was written. Is it possible?

Comment: I suggest checking out my answer on this other question, I think your problem can be solved with this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102641/get-the-most-viewed-posts-in-ghost-blog