# Get the most viewed posts in Ghost blog

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, ghost-blog

I want to make a list of the most viewed posts in the last month. I found almost zero info about this.

Is it possible? Can it be done using Google Analytics or something?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done with the built-in toolset of Ghost. Since I have found almost zero info about this like you, I decided to create my own implementation.

First, you have to integrate GA tracking to your site. Here's more info on how to do that:
https://help.ghost.org/article/16-google-analytics

I created a custom Ghost helper to download Google Analytics metrics. Please note that setting up a custom helper is unfortunately not very well documented and definitely not supported.

Here's the Github repository with the source code: https://github.com/conwid/GhostHelpers

Check out the project's wiki.

- There information on how to set up a custom helper: https://github.com/conwid/GhostHelpers/wiki/Adding-a-custom-helper-to-Ghost
- And there's information on how to set up the Google Analytics helper specifically: https://github.com/conwid/GhostHelpers/wiki/Top

I have also written a couple of blog posts about this that could give you more info:

- [Create custom helpers to add functionality to your Ghost blog](https://dotnetfalcon.com/create-custom-helpers-to-add-functionality-to-your-ghost-blog/)
- [Creating a most popular posts page with a custom ghost helper to download Google Analytics data](https://dotnetfalcon.com/creating-a-most-popular-posts-page-with-a-custom-ghost-helper-to-download-google-analytics-data/)

And finally you can check out the end results of using the helper on my blog: https://dotnetfalcon.com/greatest-hits/

(Sorry for the shameless self-marketing, but as I said, I found almost zero info about this also everywhere else).